# Framework 4.6.2 SharePoint Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)

Tags: sharepoint-server, .net

We can not access certain pages in _Layouts after installing Framework 4.6.2
Any tips or suggestions?

**Sharepoint uls log:**

> Authentication Authorization      agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request.
>   IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|ffrm\xxx, ClaimsCount=33
>                                                         f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea
>
> General                           8nca    Medium      **Application error when
>   access /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx,** 
>                                                     Error=Un composant externe a levé une exception.
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult
>   result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String
>   cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode,
>   Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.Build...   f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea...Manager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp)
>                                                         à System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>                                                         à System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   ...   f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea... 
>                                                         à System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)   f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea
>
> Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  **System.Web.HttpCompileException: *Un composant
>   externe a levé une exception.***
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult
>   result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String
>   cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode,
>   Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWit... f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea...hNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp)
>                                                         à System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>                                                         à System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> à System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)   f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea
>
> General                           ajlz0   High        **Getting Error Message
>   for Exception System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)**: Un
>   composant externe a levé une exception.
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult
>   result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String
>   cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode,
>   Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.W...   f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea...eb.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)
>                                                         à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp)
>                                                         à System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>                                                         à System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecuti... f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea...onStep.Execute()
>
> à System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)   f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea Logging
>   Correlation Data          xmnv    Medium 
>     Site=/  f4dc1f9e-62eb-10c1-77cd-7bf420000bea

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If its just an error to `_layouts`, the first thing I'd do is run `psconfig -cmd secureresources` to reapply security settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will do this tonight, nevertheless by running iisrest the problem disappears momentarily to reappear for another page later in _laouts

Comment: Always the same problem :
"... **Application error when access** /_layouts/15/GAA/GAA_Contact.aspx, 
Error=Un composant externe a levé une exception.
   à System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() 
   à System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler ..."

Comment: You almost threw me referencing that custom page.  Go to IIS and make sure that the .NET version of  your web application is set to 2.0 and not 4.0 (assuming SharePoint 2013 or lower)

Comment: Grr me.  Too early in the morning.  What SharePoint version and server version are you running.